# How to compare arrays for content equality

Tags: c++, arrays, equality

Is there a way to get the equality operators to work for comparing arrays of the same type?

For example:

```
int x[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int y[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int z[4] = {1,2,3,5};
if (x == y) cout << "It worked!"
```

I'm aware that as is, it's just comparing pointer values - but I was hoping there's some kind of typedef trick or something like that so it wouldn't need a loop or a memcmp call.

Comment: I suggest using a `vector` instead of an array for this.

Comment: I nearly always use vectors, so I'd agree, but in this case the number of elements will be constantly 5 and that will never change, so I thought a simple array would be better.

Comment: why do you think it would be better? You can perfectly work with constant sized-vectors.

Comment: That's the perfect use case for an `std::array` then.

Comment: Generally, there's no trick that will avoid iterating over the array elements. You can use `std::equal` from the standard library (see answers below) but it still contains a loop.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Not necessarily... the STL implementation can (some do) check the type of the container and opt to use `memcmp` (which in turn can be vectorized) if the types can be compared bitwise or else fallback to iteration if it is not safe to compare bitwise.

Comment: Interesting :) How do I force a vector to stay at constant size?

Comment: @w00te - A vector keeps it's size if you don't add any more elements. :-)

Comment: I'm aware, haha.  Was more of a defensive programming question since everyone works on everything where I am :p

Comment: You can find some solutions on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12866413/5740428

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the standard [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) algorithm (or [`std::ranges::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/equal) since C++20):

```cpp
if (std::equal(x, std::end(x), y)) cout << "It worked!";
// or since C++20
if (std::ranges::equal(x, y)) cout << "It worked!";
```

Comment: a minor improvement would be to not use the magic '4' in the solution and use the std::end and std::begin acordingly
```std::equal( std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::begin(y) )```

Answer (score 11):

Use `std::equal` as:

```
if(std::equal(x, x+ xsize, y)) std::cout << "equal";
```

It checks equality of elements in the same order. That means, according to `std::equal` the following arrays are not equal.

```
int x[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int y[4] = {1,2,4,3}; //order changed!
```

Comment: The `set_difference` part is wrong... that algorithm requires as a precondition that the two ranges are sorted, which means that it cannot be applied to the example above --and will provide the wrong output, probably something in the lines of `[3,3]`. Then again, if you are going to order the arrays before calling the algorithm, and you only care about equality, the `std::equal` will suffice and will be less expensive than `std::set_difference`

Comment: @David: Yeah. I saw the doc, and realized that. Removed the incorrect part.

Answer (score 8):

Another way would be to wrap your arrays in the `std::array` template, which will make a small wrapper class for the array. Everything works pretty much like normal, except that you get a default definition of `operator=`, so you can use `==` as normal to do the expected thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the arrays are of the same type and length, you could use `memcmp` to test for equality, that is equality of value and position:

```
int array1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int array2[4] = {5, 6, 7, 8};

if (memcmp(array1, array2, sizeof(array1)) == 0)
{
    cout << "arrays are equal" << "\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "arrays are not equal" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It's a shame this answer didn't get more upvotes; people seem to be allergic to C even though it can sometimes make the code better (viz. `+ 4` and `sizeof`).

Comment: Using `memcp` for equality comparison may be a huge footgun. It unnecessarily relies on `int` having no padding bits (which isn't guaranteed), and if `memcp` is a possible solution, then it might be used by `std::equal`. Don't use low-level tricks like these, or at least add assertions to make sure they don't break.

Answer (score 0):

###### Solution A - Use `std::array`<sup>(C++11)</sup>

```cpp
std::array<int> x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::array<int> y = {1, 2, 3, 4};
if (x == y) // true
```

`std::array` avoids a lot of C-style array problems in general, so you might want to replace all your uses of `int[]` with it.

###### Solution B - Use `std::span`s<sup>(C++20)</sup>

```cpp
if (std::span{x} == std::span{y})
```

`std::span` is a lightweight non-owning view into an array.
Wrapping a range in a `std::span` and using the `==` operator should be just as cheap as using standard library algorithms.

###### Solution C - Use `std::equal`<sup>(C++98)</sup> or `std::ranges::equal`<sup>(C++20)</sup>

```cpp
if (std::ranges::equal(x, y))

// the last argument is optional, but may be helpful for optimizations
if (std::equal(std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::begin(y), std::end(y))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its also useful to note here that C++ does not allow you to overload `operator==` without at least 1 user-defined type.  That would be the "nice" solution, but even if you could, it would probably be a bad idea.  Arrays in C++...are sort of evil woodland creatures.

`std::equal` is probably your best bet.  Though you could probably do what you want with a **gasp** macro, i think that is gacky.