# How to pass char type array to a function and copy 1st char array to 2nd chart array and compare it using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char

**Here is what I want:**
Declare a character array of size 15 to store character (string input) value from the user. Now perform the following tasks:

- Pass the array to function copy().
- Define another array of the same size in above function. Copy the values of the first array to the second array and display on the console.
- From function Copy() pass both arrays to function compare(). At that function compare both arrays and display message "Equal" if the condition is fulfilled.

**Here is my code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

void mycopy(char array);
int main(){
//Using Loop to input an Array from user

char array[15];
int i;
cout << "Please Enter your 15 characters" << endl;
cout << "**************************************************" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    cin >> array[i];
}

// output each array element's value
cout << "Please Enter your 15 characters" << endl;
cout << "**************************************************" << endl;
cout << "Element" << setw(13) << "Value" << endl;
for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    cout << setw(7) << j << setw(13) << array[j] << endl;
}

mycopy(array[15]);

return 0;
}

void mycopy(char array[15]) {

char array1[15];
strncpy_s(array1, array, 15);
cout << "The output of the copied Array" << endl;
cout << "**************************************************" << endl;
cout << "Element" << setw(13) << "Value" << endl;
for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    cout << setw(7) << j << setw(13) << array1[j] << endl;
}
```

}

The above code is to pass the array to function Copy() and copy the values of the 1st array to the 2nd char array but the code generates an exception due to the invalid parameter is passed.  As I have searched the stack overflow but I didn't find any similar question that could solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to put a semicolon after the prototype for `mycopy()`, which is above `main()`.

Comment: And `void mycopy(char * array)` in the prototype you forgot `*`

Comment: @Mark Thanks but now it gives me other error

Comment: Should i update the code now and ask for the new error?

Comment: Hasn't been answered yet, so go ahead.

Comment: While you're at it, you forgot to include cstring to get `strncpy`, and `mycopy` has an uneven brace count.

Comment: Now please see the question once again

Comment: Unless you've been assigned this as homework just to learn about C-style arrays, don't do this at all. `std::string`s are much easier to handle.

Comment: i have just reply the strncpy with strncpy_s and the code is now working fine. thanks every one for you help

Comment: but I have passed invalid parameter plz see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `strncpy_s`, it is non-standard. Instead, use `strncpy` as you were originally. In order to use it, you need to include `cstring`.

```
#include <cstring>
```

Your prototype and definition for `mycopy()` are different. Your prototype takes a `char` but your definition takes a `char` array. Make them both take an array. Either of the following three will work the same:

```
void mycopy(char* array);
void mycopy(char array[]);
void mycopy(char array[15]);
```

When you are calling `mycopy()` in `main()` you are attempting to access the array at the 15th index and pass that character to the function. This is wrong because the 15th index is out of bounds and because the function takes a pointer to a `char` array, not a `char`. You need to just pass the pointer to the array.

```
mycopy(array);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark , so it problem in my Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Marks what about the last task?

Comment: Marks what about the last task?

Comment: There are answers to that problem elsewhere on SO, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866413/comparing-arrays-for-equality-in-c). You could also use `strcmp()`, but you would need to make sure the strings are null terminated for that.

Comment: but dear @Mark i facing problem in doing it through function, as asked to pass the both array from the copy fun()

Comment: @SangeenKhan Let's move this to a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156422/how-to-pass-char-type-array-to-a-function-and-copy-1st-char-array-to-2nd-chart-ar).

Comment: I need your help

Comment: I need you help