# Are two arrays equal function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, compare

I am trying to do function which compare to arrays and returns true if they are same. Now the arrays are simple, it will be advanced later but I am stuck on the `testEqual` function.
So here is code

```
int n = 5;
int array[5] = {5,10,3,4,7};
bubbleSort(pole,n);

int array2[5] = {3,4,5,7,10};
testEqual( array , array2 , "bubbleSort");
```

And here is `testEqual` function I need to remake on arrays but I don't know how.

```
bool testEqual(int i1, int i2, const string testName) {
    bool myresult = (i1 == i2);
    return myresult;
}
```

The other functions like bubbleSort are fine I just need to remake `testEqual`.

Comment: [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) (The array overloads for [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) will also be useful)

Comment: What does qualify as "two arrays are equal"?

Comment: Your function tests just two numbers, not arrays. You should probably pass pointers to your arrays as function parameters, together with array size, and then run a loop over all elements inside the function. That should get you on the right track.

Comment: @user1264727, adding the remark that you should first test that the sizes are equal, I would upvote this as an answer especially given the lack of effort / understanding shown in the question.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273340/array-contents-equality-in-c

Comment: @CompuChip I specifically omitted that because the array size is hardcoded, and given that this is obviously a homework type of problem, that can be dismissed. Perhaps I am wrong not to mention it even in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following may help:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
bool isEqual(const T (&lhs)[N], const T (&rhs)[N])
{
    return std::equal(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), std::begin(rhs));
}
```

If you use `std::array`, you have that for free. (And the syntax is more friendly).

Comment: Nice, it fails at compile time if the sizes don't match. I like.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two arrays you could use standard algorithm `std::equal`.

For example

```
bool testEqual( const int *first1, const int *last1, const int *first2, const int *last2 )
{
    return std::equal( first1, last1, first2, last2 );
}
```

It can be called the following way

```
testEqual( array, array + 5, array2, array2 + 5 );
```

As for your function then it is invalid.

It simply compares two integers and it is not clear what is the meaning of the third parameter

```
bool testEqual(int i1, int i2, const string testName) {
    bool myresult = (i1 == i2);
    return myresult;
}
```

Comment: `std::equal` only takes three iterators. You'll need a separate test that the sizes match.

Comment: @ Mike Seymour You are wrong. The family of std::equal algorithms was enlarged in C++ 2011 (or in C++ 2014 because now I look through the C++ 2014 Draft.)

Comment: Not in my copy of C++11. 25.2.11 only specifies overloads for three iterators, and three iterators plus a predicate.

Comment: @ Mike Seymour Now I look through the C++ 2014 Draft # 3691.:)

Comment: @ Mike Seymour I think that GCC already included it though I did not check.

Answer (score 0):

i see it the same as H2CO3 "what qualifies as equal?"

the approach with std::equal does not match to the arrays you are providing...std::equal will take same elements AND order.

I modified the example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/)

```
int main () {
  int myints[] = {20,40,60,80,100};               
  int myints2[] = {20,100,60,40,100};               
  std::vector<int>myvector (myints2,myints2+5);     // myvector: 20 40 60 80 100

  // using default comparison:
  if ( std::equal (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myints) )
    std::cout << "The contents of both sequences are equal.\n";
  else
    std::cout << "The contents of both sequences differ.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

resulting in

```
The contents of both sequences differ.
```

so for using std::equal, you should sort them before

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal). For example :

```
#include <algorithm>

int *ints;
ints = new int[10];

bool EqualArray(const Object& obj)
{
   return std::equal(ints,ints + 10, obj.ints);
}
```

Of course you can also overload the `operator==` for other things. Unfortunately you can't overload it for primitive arrays, because overloading operators is only allowed if at least one argument is a class (or struct) type. But you could override it to compare vector with array. Something like:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc, size_t S>
bool operator==(std::vector<T, Alloc> v, const T (&a)[S])
{
    return v.size() == S && std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
}
```

(this takes reference to array not degraded to pointer to check it's declared size first and is therefore safe).

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: Simply linking to another [so] question is not particularly appropriate as an answer. It's preferred to flag the question as a duplicate, or simply post a comment instead.